# how to do shell navigation using python

Tags: python, linux, shell, navigation, popen

I want to cd to another directory with python which I want to execute this command on the shell its run in to navigate to the directory.

```
command = 'cd ../../../'  
os.popen(command)
```

this should navigate my shell to the new directory

Comment: Is your goal simply to replicate the cd command, or to change your working directory for the rest of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.chdir('/path/to/dir')
```

The docs for os.chdir are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os-file-dir).

Comment: import os, sys
    def nav():
        path = os.getcwd()
        item = path.split('/')
        name = sys.argv[1]
        match = name
        slash=""
        inc=-1
        length = len(item)
        for i in item:
            inc+=1
            if i != match:
                continue
            else:
                break
        ink = 0
        string='/'
        while ink != inc:
            ink+=1
            string += item[ink]+"/"
        print string    
        os.chdir(string)
    nav()